# Clojure Immutant server says The requested resource is not available

Tags: clojure, jboss7.x

I tried to deploy my clojure web application to Immutant server. The deployment went fine and the server is running. But when I try to access it from a browser it says :

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 -

JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report

JBWEB000068: message

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.

JBoss Web/7.2.0.Final
```

The web application has no error and runs fine on my local system and jetty on the server

```
lein immutant run -b 173.255.244.160
```

The console output:

```
 Starting Immutant: /home/devasia/.lein/immutant/current/jboss/bin/standalone.sh -b     173.255.244.160
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /home/devasia/.lein/immutant/current/jboss

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -  Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

=========================================================================

09:30:23,517 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.2.0.CR1
09:30:23,813 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.0.4.GA
09:30:23,922 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: JBoss AS    7.x.incremental.673 "TBD" starting
09:30:25,133 INFO  [org.immutant.core.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) Initializing Immutant Core Subsystem
09:30:25,141 INFO  [org.immutant.common.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 15) Initializing Immutant Common Subsystem
09:30:25,145 INFO  [org.immutant.bootstrap.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) Initializing Immutant App Bootstrap Subsystem
09:30:25,151 INFO  [org.immutant.messaging.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) Initializing Immutant Messaging Subsystem
09:30:25,151 INFO  [org.immutant.daemons.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) Initializing Immutant Daemons Subsystem
09:30:25,155 INFO  [org.immutant.xa.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) Initializing Immutant XA Subsystem
09:30:25,156 INFO  [org.immutant.jobs.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) Initializing Immutant Jobs Subsystem
09:30:25,160 INFO  [org.projectodd.polyglot.cache.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) Initializing Polyglot Cache Subsystem
09:30:25,162 INFO  [org.immutant.web.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 3) Initializing Immutant Web Subsystem
09:30:25,164 INFO  [org.projectodd.polyglot.hasingleton.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) Initializing HA-Singleton Subsystem
09:30:25,164 INFO  [org.immutant.cache.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) Initializing Immutant Cache Subsystem
09:30:25,175 INFO  [org.immutant.core.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) Welcome to Immutant AS - http://immutant.org/
09:30:25,176 INFO  [org.immutant.core.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10)   version........... 1.x.incremental.800
09:30:25,176 INFO  [org.immutant.core.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10)   build............. 800
09:30:25,177 INFO  [org.immutant.core.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10)   revision.......... 3ef999cedd68d79d283803785e204ad1243e27dd +modifications
09:30:25,177 INFO  [org.immutant.core.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10)   built with:
09:30:25,180 INFO  [org.immutant.core.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10)     HornetQ......... 2.3.0.CR1 (buzzzzz!, 122)
09:30:25,180 INFO  [org.immutant.core.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10)     JBossAS......... 7.x.incremental.673
09:30:25,180 INFO  [org.immutant.core.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10)     Clojure......... 1.5.0
09:30:25,181 INFO  [org.immutant.core.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10)     Infinispan...... 5.2.1.Final
09:30:25,181 INFO  [org.immutant.core.as] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10)     Quartz.......... 2.1.5
09:30:25,482 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015883: No security realm defined for native management service; all access will be unrestricted.
09:30:25,490 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO Version 3.0.7.GA
09:30:25,494 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
09:30:25,494 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015884: No security realm defined for http management service; all access will be unrestricted.
09:30:25,500 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.7.GA
09:30:25,514 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBoss Remoting version 3.2.14.GA
09:30:25,564 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
09:30:25,584 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
09:30:25,631 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.http.api] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015102: Unable to load console module for slot main, disabling console
09:30:25,643 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
09:30:25,671 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
09:30:25,674 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.15.Final)
09:30:25,695 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
09:30:25,708 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.15.Final
09:30:25,781 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
09:30:26,193 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-/173.255.244.160:8080
09:30:26,199 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-/173.255.244.160:8080
09:30:26,397 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS017100: Listening on 173.255.244.160:4447
09:30:26,406 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory    /home/devasia/.lein/immutant/current/jboss/standalone/deployments
09:30:26,441 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "listing.clj" (runtime-name: "listing.clj")
09:30:26,500 WARN  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011600: AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux, install LibAIO to enable the AIO journal
09:30:26,527 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Delirium' 5.2.1.Final
09:30:26,643 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (MSC service thread 1-2) HQ221001: live server is starting with configuration HornetQ Configuration (clustered=false,backup=false,sharedStore=true,journalDirectory=/home/devasia/.lein/immutant/current/jboss/standalone/data/messagingjournal,bindingsDirectory=/home/devasia/.lein/immutant/current/jboss/standalone/data/messagingbindings,largeMessagesDirectory=/home/devasia/.lein/immutant/current/jboss/standalone/data/messaginglargemessages,pagingDirectory=/home/devasia/.lein/immutant/current/jboss/standalone/data/messagingpaging)
09:30:26,646 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (MSC service thread 1-2) HQ221008: Waiting to obtain live lock
09:30:26,850 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (MSC service thread 1-2) HQ221017: Using NIO Journal
09:30:27,007 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (MSC service thread 1-2) HQ221039: Waiting to obtain live lock
09:30:27,007 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (MSC service thread 1-2) HQ221040: Live Server Obtained live lock
09:30:27,231 INFO  [org.infinispan.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform MBean server.
09:30:27,235 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS010281: Started __recoveryInfoCacheName__ cache from polyglot container
09:30:27,273 INFO  [org.infinispan.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform MBean server.
09:30:27,274 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS010281: Started default cache from polyglot container
09:30:27,445 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (MSC service thread 1-2) HQ221024: Started Netty Acceptor version 3.6.2.Final-c0d783c 173.255.244.160:5455 for CORE protocol
09:30:27,447 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (MSC service thread 1-2) HQ221024: Started Netty Acceptor version 3.6.2.Final-c0d783c 173.255.244.160:5445 for CORE protocol
09:30:27,449 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (MSC service thread 1-2) HQ221009: Server is now live
09:30:27,449 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (MSC service thread 1-2) HQ221003: HornetQ Server version 2.3.0.CR1 (buzzzzz!, 122) [0adf02af-8edd-11e2-a868-0d52633a1c04] 
09:30:27,500 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
09:30:27,504 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
09:30:40,249 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.0)
09:30:43,330 INFO  [com.mchange.v2.log.MLog] (MSC service thread 1-8) MLog clients using log4j logging.
09:30:49,880 INFO  [immutant.runtime] (MSC service thread 1-8) Initialized listing from :ring options in project.clj
09:30:49,916 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS018210: Register web context: 
09:30:50,417 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "listing.clj" (runtime-name : "listing.clj")
09:30:50,426 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
09:30:50,427 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
09:30:50,427 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.x.incremental.673 "TBD" started in 27321ms - Started 135 of 180 services (45 services are passive or on-demand)
```

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit with oracle java 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing the project.clj, specifically the :ring map. When you say it runs fine on your local system, is that with Jetty or Immutant? I would try to make sure it runs locally on Immutant first. One thing that concerns me is the lack of a log message like "Registering ring handler at sub-context path: /*". That either indicates a bug on our end or possibly an error with the :handler entry in your :ring map. Is this a very simple app that you could maybe publish somewhere (github?) with steps to reproduce? If so, I'd be happy to try running it locally myself.

Comment: it is running fine on my local system in immutant. My local system is Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit with open-jdk 7. It is a very simple project and can be viewed here: [github project] (https://github.com/devasiajoseph/listing). Thank you for replying

Comment: Do you think there is a bug in 1.x.incremental.800? I updated immutant  (from 1.x.incremental.794) and now it stopped working on my localhost too ? And same is the case on the server I installed 1.x.incremental.794(the version that was already on my system) and it is working well on the server.

Comment: I just confirmed it's a bug on our side, Devasia. Thanks for the test app and sorry for the trouble. Please use 794 until I can get a fix pushed (I'm at Clojure/West this week, so may be a day or two)

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. And great job with the server!!! Currently the best solution for web applications in clojure

Comment: Devasia, give the latest incremental build (801) a try at your convenience. You should be able to get it by running 'lein immutant install' again. Thanks for helping us make Immutant better! :)